# Deploying and Using Cloud SQL in GAE

Tags: wordpress, google-app-engine, google-cloud-sql

I'm trying to install Wordpress using this Mac version. I was able to deploy it locally using the following settings:

```
define('DB_NAME', 'db_name');
/** Local environment MySQL login info */
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
define('DB_USER', 'root');
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'whatever');
```

However, when I tried to deploy it using Cloud SQL, I can't seem to figure out the correct settings.

In the DB_HOST, I have tried the following:

- `:/cloudsql/project-id:custom-db-instance`
- `:/cloudsql/project-id:region:custom-db-instance`
- `:/cloudsql/project-id:wordpress`
- `:/cloudsql/project-id:region:wordpress`
- IP address of Cloud SQL Server

Using app.yaml, I have set app.yaml env_variables to the following:

- MYSQL_DSN: mysql:unix_socket=/cloudsql/INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME;dbname=DATABASE
- MYSQL_USER: root
- MYSQL_PASSWORD: ''

I'm wondering what is the real setting because the documentation does not seem unified. Here are the documentation I read:

- https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/php/cloud-sql/
- https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/appengine-php-wordpress-starter-project/
- https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-php-wordpress-starter-project

Answer (score 0):

You are using appengine? Make sure you have authorized your appengine process in the Access Control tab of the instance. In all your examples, they are all Instance connection name of your instance after "/cloudsql/". You can find that in your instance details page. For a v1 instance, the format is :. For a V2 instance, the format is ::.

Comment: The instance connection name says `project-id:region:wordpress`. How should I format the host? I tried `::/cloudsql/project-id:region:wordpress`. The SQL Instance Details Page also says "Apps in this project: All authorized" since both GAE and Cloud SQL are all in one project.

Comment: You should not use DB_HOST. Edit your app.yaml as in https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/php/cloud-sql/. Then just try the code followed in the page:
$app['database'] = function () use ($app) {
    $dsn = getenv('MYSQL_DSN');
    $user = getenv('MYSQL_USER');
    $password = getenv('MYSQL_PASSWORD');
    if (!isset($dsn, $user) || false === $password) {
        throw new Exception('Set MYSQL_DSN, MYSQL_USER, and MYSQL_PASSWORD environment variables');
    }
    $db = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password);
    return $db;
};

Comment: I have also read about that. Wordpress does not use DSN, though. I think I'm just going to use Google Cloud SQL and use the Cloud SQL Launcher, instead.